# Not Connected to Server Postgres database , showing timeout expired

Tags: postgresql

I am currently working on Spring Boot project which is connected to Postgres database. I am using PG Admin tool to connected to database. While I am running my project, I am getting exception and that is related to database.

The password I am giving is correct, still it is not connecting to the database. I am not using any AWS services.

[image]

How I can resolve this issues related to timeout expired?

Comment: Betting you have a firewall that is blocking the Postgres port.

Comment: Adrian few hours before it was connection but just few minutes before it showing timeout expired. Could you guide me how to do unblocking the Postgres port?

Comment: Have no idea as you have not  said where the remote server is located.